# Export React component with two property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI and I have to export my components like this:

```
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

...

export default withStyles(styles)(Users);
```

Now I started to use [`i18next`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) to use internationalization in my project but it want me to export my component like this:

`export default translate("common")(Users);`

The question is how can I satisfy both? How can I export with `withStyles` and `translate`?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those pieces of code produce a new component, so you can feed the result of one into the other. Done in one line, it would look like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(translate("common")(Users));
```

Or if it makes it easier to follow, here it is split on two lines.

```
const TranslatedUsers = translate("common")(Users);
export default withStyles(styles)(TranslatedUsers);
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of higher-order components is to provide a way for components to be efficiently composed:

```
export default translate("common")(
  withStyles(styles)(Users)
);
```

It can be flattened with composition helpers, e.g. `recompose`:

```
import { compose } from 'recompose'

export default compose(
  translate("common"),
  withStyles(styles)
)(Users);
```